# One layout overlapping the whole screen in constraint layout with only one device OnePlus 5 as of now

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have made the following layout :

[image]

using LinearLayout and child ConstraintLayout with NestedScrollView. 
**Problem**: The layout is working fine in almost all devices but the problem seems to be Oneplus 5 with having resolution 1080*1920. Here's the layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar_with_filter_back" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:fillViewport = "true"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/banner"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="165dp" />


        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/win_card"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:elevation="@dimen/_8sdp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_10sdp"
            app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp">


                        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="0.4"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:scaleType="fitXY"
                            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                            app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true">

                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                                <ImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/exec_business_icon"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                                    android:src="@drawable/icon_dairy" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/exec_business_iconname"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                                    android:background="@color/exec_card_second_title"
                                    android:fontFamily="@font/boutrosasma_regular"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:text="Foods"
                                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_h" />
                            </RelativeLayout>

                        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="0dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:gravity="center">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tvRname"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                                android:ellipsize="end"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/boutrosasma_bold"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:text="@string/exe_size"
                                android:textColor="@color/exec_card_second_title"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_h_valve"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="0dp"
                            android:layout_weight="2"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/fb_sr_bu"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                                android:ellipsize="end"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/boutrosasma_regular"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:text="SR"
                                android:textColor="@color/exec_card_size_val_color"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_h"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/fb_size_val_bu"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
                                android:ellipsize="end"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/boutrosasma_bold"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:text="56.9"
                                android:maxLength="5"
                                android:textColor="@color/exec_card_size_val_color"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/_14ssp"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/fb_bn_bu"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                                android:ellipsize="end"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/boutrosasma_regular"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:text="BN"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
                                android:textColor="@color/exec_card_size_val_color"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_h"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:src="@drawable/layer_5" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="0dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:gravity="center">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tvgrowth"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                                android:ellipsize="end"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/boutrosasma_bold"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:text="@string/exe_growth"
                                android:textColor="@color/exec_card_second_title"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_h_valve"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />
                        </LinearLayout>


                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/fb_growth_bu"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:ellipsize="end"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/boutrosasma_bold"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="+7.0%"
                            android:maxLength="6"
                            android:textColor="@color/exec_growth_val_color"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/_14ssp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card_topplayer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:elevation="@dimen/_8sdp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_10sdp"
            app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/win_card"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/top_player_back"
                android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/top_player"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/boutrosasma_bold"
                    android:text="@string/business_unit_top"
                    android:textColor="@color/exec_card_size_val_color" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/orientation_btn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/orientation" />

            </RelativeLayout>


                <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_200sdp"
                    android:id="@+id/business_lineChart"/>

                <View
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:alpha="0.2"
                    android:background="@color/horizontal_line"/>

               <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                   android:id="@+id/legendRecyclerView"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_gravity="center"
                   android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp"/>
            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Tests**:

1. Tried with Oreo/ Pie devices
2. Created one emulator having same resolution running oreo 8.1

I am unable to regenerate the issue yet. 
The Oneplus5 screen is which i have received from review:

[image]

Please suggest if i should do any changes with the layout. One idea that i am thinking is of not using constraint layout and use linear or relative instead of that but the main problem is setting up the first cardview with same alignment with that background image as that background bottle image is not even covering the half of the screen so i center_vertical will not work with all screen sizes for first cardview. 
Please give some suggestions.

Comment: You should not use `match_parent` in a child of _ConstraintLayout_. Use `0dp` (_match_constraints_) instead with the appropriate constraints set. Also, each child view of _ConstraintLayout_ must be constrained vertically _and_ horizontally. You are missing constraints. There may be other things, but start with these.

Comment: I have made it working but i want to know why are these missing things working on majority of the devices?

Comment: `match_parent` is not supported and I have seen unusual behavior when it is used. It could be just that.